# Adding a .png when hovering

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have tooltip show a png, when i hover a part of a css map. But i am not savvy enough to make it work :C

I have tried to add in the png, but when i do it either completely removes the tooltip or the tooltip says undefined, or it cant find the image i am trying to embed into the tooltip

```
document.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
  if (e.target.tagName == 'path') {
    var content = e.target.dataset.name;
    mapDetails.innerHTML = content;
    mapDetails.innerHTML = `<img src="image.png" alt="text for image"/>`
    mapDetails.style.opacity = "100%";
  }
  else {
    mapDetails.style.opacity = "0%";
  }
});
```

Comment: You could set the image as the background image of the tooltip. That also makes it easier to check the hover state with `:hover`.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly without seeing more of your code, but here:
mapDetails.innerHTML = content;
mapDetails.innerHTML = `<img src="image.png" alt="text for image"/>`

You effectively overwrite 'content' with the image, in the very next line... this can hardly be what you want? This is probably what causes the removal of the tooltip itself.
As for the src, make sure you got the relative path right. "image.png" has to be in the same folder as your html in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Not really know how you want to achieve this But maybe this helps:
https://jsfiddle.net/k7n1z32t/

```
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
  <span class="image">
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
      $(".tooltip").hover(function() {
          $('.tooltiptext').append('<div class="line"><img src="image.png" alt="image"/></div>');
      }, function() {
          $('.tooltiptext').children('.line').remove();
      });
});

</script>
```